# How do you deploy a Winusb application in C++?

Tags: visual-c++, winusb

I've developed a C++ console program to communicate with a microcontroller board using a Winusb template in Visual Studio 2017. My program is in 2 parts, a USB application using WindowsApplicationForDrivers10.0 platform which is a dll. The 2nd partis an exe application which calls the aforementioned dll and also uses WindowsApplicationForDrivers10.0 platform. The program works fine from within Visual Studio. I followed the procedure here to deploy: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-deploying-a-visual-cpp-application-by-using-a-setup-project?view=vs-2019
 Unfortunately the deployed program is unable to communicate over USB on a different computer.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Alan